# I have a problem with this query, it says that " Not Unique table/alias 'ownertbl' " what should I do?

Tags: mysql-error-1066

```
DELETE ownertbl.*, motorcycletbl.*, transactiontbl.*  
from (ownertbl 
INNER JOIN motorcycletbl on ownertbl.plate_no = motorcycletbl.plate_no) 
INNER JOIN transactiontbl on motorcycletbl.plate_no = transactiontbl.plate_no , (ownertbl 
INNER JOIN motorcycletbl on ownertbl.body_no = motorcycletbl.body_no) INNER JOIN transactiontbl on motorcycletbl.body_no = transactiontbl.body_no 
WHERE ownertbl.plate_no = 'ABB1234' or ownertbl.body_no= 'T-0000'
```

Comment: I also tried this query                                                                                                      DELETE own.*, motor.*, trans.* from (ownertbl own INNER JOIN motorcycletbl motor on own.plate_no = motor.plate_no) INNER JOIN transactiontbl trans on motor.plate_no = trans.plate_no,                                                                                   (ownertbl own INNER JOIN motorcycletbl motor on own.body_no = motor.body_no) INNER JOIN transactiontbl trans on motor.body_no = trans.body_no WHERE own.plate_no = 'ABB1234' or own.body_no= 'T-0000'

Comment: i tried giving them an alias but it still doesnt work